# Set flash parameter AllowScriptAccess to 'sameDomain' instead 'always'

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I am using prime faces jar in my web application. The prime faces jar contain `utility.js` file.
I need to set flash parameter `AllowScriptAccess` value to `'sameDomain'` instead `'always'` in `utility.js` file. I am not interested to edit jar file manually.

It is challenging one. Anybody have idea about this let me know pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put a modified copy of that *utility.js* file in your resources folder an load it using the `<f:facet name="last">` , that way your copy of the file should be loaded in the end and override the js file from the jar

```
<f:facet name="last">
     <!-- load css, js or others -->
</f:facet>
```

Take a look at this [Resource ordering in PrimeFaces](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/resource-ordering-in-primefaces/)

Comment: yes Daniel but have any other way to do it because its required one more file for this simple function.

Comment: Might be... but not that I could think of right now, b.t.w modifying the jar is possible too... choose between the two options... and dont forget to accept the answer...