# Primefaces spinner does not accepts inputs from numpad

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, spinner

I'm using primefaces 3.2 in my JSF project. For a numeric field I used the spinner component to restrict the user to input only numeric values. However, the spinner has a strange issue! It does not accept inputs from numpad of the keyboard.

I checked the showcase but there is no problem there. I think the showcase is for v3.3. If this is a bug in v3.2 do you have any idea to fix this without upgrading to v3.3?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Its indeed was a known issue [Issue 3711:   Spinner support numeric pad key in](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3711)

It was fixed in the [revision N#7405 of the spinner.js](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/spinner/spinner.js?r=7405)

You can take a look at the *diff* between 7220 and 7405 revisions of the *spinner.js* files (in case that you want to override with a newer version)

[spinner.js r7220 vs. r7405](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/diff?spec=svn7405&r=7405&format=side&path=/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/spinner/spinner.js&old_path=/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/spinner/spinner.js&old=7220)

**INMO** you better just upgrade...

---

Another possible solution is to take the updated *spinner.js* and put it in your *resource* folder and load it using the [*last facet* like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14018124/617373)